# How to draw "stacked blocks" with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I want to draw using tikz a figure which looks like the following:

[image]

I started writing it using nodes and positioning them using `right of =`, `above of =` but I don't know how to avoid using hard coded shifts, minimum width and positioning.

I am looking for the cleanest way to draw these kind of diagrams using tikz in order to be able to:

- scale the graph
- easily resize for example the hardware box and have the kernel and msr module boxes resized automatically  (they can be specified as a percentage of the hardware box)

I am not necessarily looking for the exact tikz code for this diagram, but for tricks that may help me in order to better understand how one can cleverly locates nodes in a tikz graph.

Comment: I have a feeling that this either is already implemented in some way, or it will be a tough and long job to make a good implementation + good interface. But let's wait if someone comes with a nice solution.

Comment: It would be helpful to see how you implemented this using `right of=` and `above of=` in the form of a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help have something to start with.

Comment: @PeterGrill I dind't implement it, I just started and it quickly becomes a nightmare and ugly code with xshift=-12mm, minimumwidth=3cm and other hard coded stuff that will prevent any modification.

Comment: Nightmare or not, I still think you should post your attempt that produces the diagram above. Also would be helpful if you put some thought into how would you want to specify what you are trying to draw. For instance, do you think having a macro to specify the number of blocks, their size and text content for each row makes sense.  This will also help to encapsulate what kind of limitations you can live with.

Comment: @PeterGrill I guess I asked my question a little bit too early before clearly defining my needs. I'll update the question this evening with more information. Thanks.

Comment: @ManuelSelva have you defined your needs yet? I have a few ideas about this, but I'd want to see what your desired input is before I put too much time into it.